# Conda doesn't find local package to install, although it's present in the environment's conda-bld directory

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, packaging, miniconda

I have built a conda package from my PyPI package using `conda-build`.

```
$ cd
$ conda skeleton pypi climate_indices
$ ll climate_indices/
total 6
-rw-r--r-- 1 DELL 197121  107 Sep 10 10:02 bld.bat
-rw-r--r-- 1 DELL 197121   81 Sep 10 10:02 build1.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 DELL 197121 1088 Sep  9 15:29 meta.yaml
$ conda-build climate_indices
$ ls -l /c/home/miniconda3/envs/packaging/conda-bld/win-64/
total 73
-rw-r--r-- 1 DELL 197121 58736 Sep 10 13:11 climate_indices-1.0.0-py37h39e3cac_0.tar.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 DELL 197121  2091 Sep 10 13:11 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 DELL 197121   707 Sep 10 13:11 repodata.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 DELL 197121   417 Sep 10 13:11 repodata.json.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 DELL 197121   825 Sep 10 13:11 repodata2.json
```

I next try to install it into the environment and this step fails:

```
$ conda install --use-local climate_indices
Solving environment: ...working... failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - climate_indices

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

It looks to me that it's maybe ignoring the `--use-local` option. Why is this not working as I expect (i.e. as described [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html#building-a-simple-package-with-conda-skeleton-pypi))?

Comment: What is the version of Python in the environment you're trying to install into?

Comment: Python 3.7 is the version used by the environment.

Comment: Is this on WSL? Where is conda installed? What shell are you using?

Comment: Windows 10, Miniconda3, using the bash shell console provided as part of git client for Windows, conda is installed along with the rest of Miniconda under /c/home/miniconda3 (or C:/home/miniconda3)

Comment: Can you try using the Anaconda Prompt to run the build and install?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem today. I was fixed (?) by adding `--offline`

```
conda install --use-local  --offline  mypackae
```